# How to make sure in Android we are using HTTPS correctly

Tags: android, https

To avoid man in the middle attack, we have written following code to talk to our server that has a valid cert issued by Go Daddy

```
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
      sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
```

Despite using the "AndroidKeyStore", we are able to talk to sites that do not have valid certificate. What are we doing wrong? Any help appreciated?